# What is my punishment if caught with a fake ID card from Poland?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, visa-refusals

I had a valid two-year visa of France. I bought an ID card of Poland from a guy by paying extra money. I never used that card for any legal issues.

When I was boarding the flight from my country, by mistake I showed the ID CARD TO AIRLINES AND THEY SEND THE COPY TO THE OFFICER JFO SITTING AT THE AIRPORT. The JFO who takes the responsibility of Schengen came to me and saw my ID card of Poland.He cancelled my France visa and gave the card to the Poland embassy.

After 3 months I applied for a visa again with my new passport with the Swiss embassy. They refused my application 2 times already.

Comment: This is actually a law question (thus only as a comment). It is not clear if this would be charged in Poland or the country you were caught in. Most probably your home country. In Germany the charges would probably be: [§276 - Procurement of false official identity documents](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p2639) and *§281 - Misuse of identity papers* German Criminal Code. The first up to 2 years, the second up to 1 year both with possible fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, the “years” in the comment by @MarkJohnson are time in jail, not bans.

Comment: I was not caught in EU,I was at my hometown airport.i was caught before at airline counter.

Comment: @Ray And what do you think happened when your false polish ID, that you were caught red handed with, arrived at the Poland embassy? One entry in the VIS system with the details and a refusal alert was probably made, which Switzerland later saw and based their refusal on.

Comment: I was caught and told to go back home.They didn’t do anything on my passport.Just cancelled my French visa.the officer took the polish card and submitted at poland embassy in my hometown.after one month I flew to Melbourne.then after 3 months applied visa with Swiss embassy and they refused.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which country were you in? What is a JFO? How could an officer in your country cancel your French visa?

Comment: I was in my home town India.JFO - junior first officer taking responsibility for Schengen.they are well trained officers sitting for each country at all international airports around the world.There job is to check with airlines if any troubles with passenger going to there countries.He has the power to cancel visa if he sees anything wrong with documentation.

Comment: @Ray That sounds why you haven't got charged or anything, they probably are embassy personnel and don't have the power to do anything more than cancel your visa

Answer (score 16):

For at least the next 5 years (time a visa application stays on the Visa Information system), it's unlikely you'll get a Schengen visa at all as using a fake ID is extremely bad for your credibility as a law-abiding traveller.

In addition, you may need to disclose the reason of the visa cancellation in other countries' visa applications (some ask for a full history), which again will hurt your credibility badly.

Comment: So you mean 5 years I won’t be allowed!

Comment: If I make appeal and fight a case saying I was scammed and just because to make my entry and exit in Europe I did this.

Comment: @Ray how exactly do you plan to claim you were "scammed"? Will you pretend you didn't know that ID cards are provided by governments (or agencies acting on behalf of them), not just purchased from "a guy"?

Comment: So basically I have the guys chat messages and also I made him payment through bank transfers.I was told it’s real ID card.Well he was a agent and lawyer.He also gave me a video proof of another person ID card.

Comment: @Ray what are you talking about? What ID did you buy, and why did you buy it? Is it the Polish national id card? If so, did you have any reason at all to believe it is genuine, you not being a polish citizen and such? I think the "next 5 years" is generous. I'd probably not expect you to ever be able to visit the Schengen area ever again, and quite likely many other places. I'm surprised you weren't charged with a crime (yet?).

Comment: I am not an expert in this area but I am surprised that you did not get into much more trouble.  Consider some of the other types of people who travel with fake ID.  Imagine that you were mistaken for one of them.

Comment: There are many people who buy this just to live in Schengen,but don’t use for legal issues.Just for local things.ive been travelling after this to USA,Australia,Hongkong..have no issues because I was not put in a jail or no police took me.This is first attempt and some people like me are having same case and try to fight a way with embassy.

Comment: @Ray if you had a legal right to live in the Schengen area, you wouldn't need the fake ID card to do so. So how is buying the fake ID card and using it to live in the Schengen area not using it "for legal issues"? It sounds like all you really mean is that you hadn't been *caught* before.

Comment: @Ray 5 years is a conservative outlook

Comment: @Ray If you really believe you were scammed, go talk to a lawyer and see what they say about your chances of a successful appeal. Meantime at least you know you can stop wasting your money on Schengen visa applications since you won’t be getting one any time soon.

Comment: Yes I will move forward with lawyer and make appeal.it was my mistake to have this ID also had a visa but sometimes we all human go crazy and make mistakes.I have no criminal records have a travel history of 18 years and travelled almost 40+ countries.

Comment: I think you're lucky that you can say that you don't have a criminal record, because what you claim to have done is a crime in most countries.

Comment: @Ray And what reason will the appeal contain that, in your opinion, the refusal is unfounded? You didn't write what the given refusal reason was (such as 'an alert has been issued in the Schengen Information System (SIS) for the purpose of refusing entry by ...') in your question. An appeal will only be successful if the refusal is found to be unfounded. A good lawyer will not accept such a case. A bad lawyer will charge you a large fee that in the end brings no result.

Comment: The refusal said - the documents are not supportive along the iternary.There is a doubt of not coming back to home country.Basically 90% of people who are refused for Schegen visa gets this reason.

Comment: They didn’t write me that I’m flagged or I’ve been into fake id card record.